# Blazor Web Assembly: downloadable font: glyf: Number of composite points in glyph 1258 exceeds maxp maxCompositePoints

Tags: firefox, fonts, blazor, glyph

In Blazor Web Assembly project I referenced Ubuntu font as default font for the project, when I load any page I got the following warning in console:

> downloadable font: glyf: Number of composite points in glyph 1258
> exceeds maxp maxCompositePoints: 165 vs 150, adjusting limit.
> (font-family: "MyFont" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src
> index:0) source: https://localhost:1111/fonts/Ubuntu-Medium.ttf

**This issue is just in Firefox browser.**

Environment: windows 10

Unfortunately I found no solution to fix it, is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not 100% sure if I interpreted the warning correctly.*

The font you're using seems to be violating the TrueTypeFont Standard.

Maybe consider using another Version of the Font. Or simply ignore the warning , if there are no further problems with this font.

Here are further sources on TTF:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/ttch01
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/otspec180/maxp

---

##### Suggestion

Apparently the font you're using is available via the google fonts API.

Here's how to get started: [link](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#overview)

Note that using this approach, your browser will fetch the fonts directly from google. Also the fonts will be in woff2 format.